# c# Modeless dialog box Dispose() not functioning as expected

Tags: c#

I am pretty new to C# and have a problem with a Windows Form project. I am
not sure if I am doing this correctly?

I have a 'Help button' on a windows form which shows a 'Modeless dialog box'.
I want this to be Modeless so the user can carry on working in the main form
and leave open the Help form and if required minimise it.

I am requiring the user to be able to press the 'Help button' again which will
simply bring the Modeless dialog box back to the front even if it is minimized.
I do not want to create a new 'Modeless Help dialog box' and end up with many
of them I just want the single one.

I have a global variable for the main form

```
FormHelp goHelpDialog = null;
```

and the handler for the 'Help button' is

```
    private void buttonHelp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // If we havent already created a HelpDialog create it and Show() it 
        // Else just bring it to the front
        if (goHelpDialog == null)
        {
            goHelpDialog = new FormHelp();

            // Show goHelpDialog as a modless dialog so dont dispose of a modeless as we want that to stay alive
            // Note Dispose() is automatically called when user closes dialog.
            goHelpDialog.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            if (goHelpDialog.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                goHelpDialog.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;

            goHelpDialog.BringToFront();
        }

        return;
    }
```

This works fine if the user keeps hitting the 'Help button'. The problem I have is when
the user closes the 'Modeless Help dialog box' and presses the 'Help button' again I 
get an assertion because

```
if (goHelpDialog == null)
```

is not null. Therefore a new 'Modeless Help dialog box' is not created. 
I assume that goHelpDialog is not being Dispose() correctly?
Your advice is appreciated thank you.

Comment: goHelpDialog.FormClosed += delegate { goHelpDialog = null; };

Comment: Thanks for your help Hans greatly appreciated that works great